# QGraphicsWidget and QGraphicsLayout spacing and sizes

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qgraphicswidget

I use `QGraphicsWidget` and `QGraphics[Linear]Layout` inside a `QGraphicsScene` to create a Node like "Widget".
Each Node has a Header, multiple `IOGraphicsWidgets` and a Footer.

The code Structure:

[image: Code structure]

The wanted layout:

[image: Node layout]

The result of the current code:

[image: Current result]

As you can see the `NodeGraphicsWidget` (the red rectangle behind the HeaderWidget) is not resized to contain all items added to it. The spacing between the `LayoutItems` is also huge and `m_centerWidgetLayout->setSpacing(0)` changed nothing. Right now I'm thinking of writing all the layouts myself, but I hope there is a better way that I can use the standard qt.

`NodeGraphicsWidget:addIOWidget(AbstractIOGraphicsWidget *ioWidget)` just adds the given `AbstractIOGraphicsWidget` to the `m_centerWidgetLayout`.

The Constructor of `NodeGraphicsWidget`:

```
NodeGraphicsWidget::NodeGraphicsWidget(NodeGraphicsWidget::WidgetCreationFunction headerCreationFunc, NodeGraphicsWidget::WidgetCreationFunction footerCreationFunc, QGraphicsItem *parent, Qt::WindowFlags wFlags):
    QGraphicsWidget(parent, wFlags)
{
    m_headerWidget = new QGraphicsWidget(this);
    m_centerWidget = new QGraphicsWidget(this);
    m_centerWidgetLayout = new QGraphicsLinearLayout(Qt::Orientation::Vertical, m_centerWidget);
    m_centerWidgetLayout->setSpacing(0);
    m_centerWidget->setLayout(m_centerWidgetLayout);
    m_footerWidget = new QGraphicsWidget(this);


    headerCreationFunc(this, m_headerWidget);
    if(footerCreationFunc != nullptr){
        footerCreationFunc(this, m_footerWidget);
    }

    setAutoFillBackground(true);

    QPalette pal;

    pal.setColor(QPalette::Window, QColor(Qt::red));

    this->setPalette(pal);

}
```

To see the full sourcecode visit: https://github.com/nidomiro/QtNodes/tree/f5426c154a4938481f00031f031507499cc0e183/src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem myself. First I forgot the root-layout of `NodeGraphicsWidget` but that didn't fix the whole issue. The main issue, the spacing between the items, wasn't the real problem. The real problem was that every `QGraphicsLinearLayout` has an margin by default and `AbstractIOGraphicsWidget` root-layout had those margins. `layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)` solved the issue.